# How to detect if a String has specific UTF-8 characters in it? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I have a list of Strings in python. Now I want to remove all the strings from the list that are special utf-8 characters. I want just the strings which include just the characters from "U+0021" to "U+00FF". So, do you know a way to detect if a String just contains these special characters?

Thanks :)

EDIT: I use Python 3

Comment: Which Python, 2 or 3?

Comment: Characters above U+00FF aren't "special"; you merely don't want them, which is entirely arbitrary.

Comment: @deceze even if they are not special, I dont want them, right :)

Comment: @frnhr I use Python 3 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latin1 encoding correspond to the 256 first utf8 characters. Say differently, if `c` is a unicode character with a code in `[0-255]`, `c.encode('latin1')` has same value as `ord(c)`.

So to test whether a string has at least one character outside the [0-255] range, just try to encode it as `latin1`. If it contains none, the encoding will succeed, else you will get a UnicodeEncodeError:

```
no_special = True
try:
    s.encode('latin1')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    no_special = False
```

BTW, as you were told in comment unicode characters outside the [0-255] range are not *special*, simply they are not in the latin1 range.

Please note that the above also accepts all control characters like `\t`, `\r` or `\n` because they are legal latin1 characters. It may or not be what you want here.

Comment: This answers is obviously only valid for Python3. It makes sense for Python2 only if `s` is a unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> all_strings = ["okstring", "bađštring", "goodstring"]
>>> acceptible = set(chr(i) for i in range(0x21, 0xFF + 1))
>>> simple_strings = filter(lambda s: set(s).issubset(acceptible), all_strings)
>>> list(simple_strings)
['okstring', 'goodstring']
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer because the question title is "How to detect if a String has specific UTF-8 characters in it? (Python)" and this answer generically allows you to check for any set of unicode characters whereas the accepted answer only checks for non-ASCII style characters.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by "special utf-8 characters" ?

If you mean every non-ascii character, then you can try:

`s.encode('ascii', 'strict')`

It will rise an UnicodeDecodeError if the string is not 100% ascii

Comment: @BlaBlaBlabli I mean more "specific" than special. The specific characters are every character which is not "U+0021" to "U+00FF". So if I find a character outside of it in my string, i want to do somethin with the string like deleting it from a lsit.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ups, I meant encode, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression.

```
import re
mylist = ['str1', 'štr2', 'str3']
regexp = re.compile(r'[^\u0021-\u00FF]')
good_strs = filter(lambda s: not regexp.search(s), mylist)
```

`[^\u0021-\u00FF]` defines a character set, meaning any one character not in the range from `\u0021` to `\u00FF`. The letter `r` before `'[\u0021-\u00FF]'` indicates raw string notation, it saves you a lot of escaping works of backslash ('\'). Without it, every backslash in a regular expression would have to be prefixed with another one to escape it.

`regexp.search(r'[\u0021-\u00FF]',s)` will scan through `s` looking for the first location where the regular expression `r'[^\u0021-\u00FF]'` produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return `None` if no match is found.

`filter()` will filter out the unwanted strings.

This answer is only valid for Python 3

Comment: I dont want to replace the characters in the string. I want just to know if there is any character outside of my utf-8 charset. You have a example like  if (re.find(r'[\u0021-\u00ff]',s))  (i dont know, I am really unfamiliar wih everythin of it

Comment: @tommitomtom Try [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

Comment: @syntonym now it matches like everything. I tried it with some chars in an if decision. I get a match with like every character

Comment: @tommitomtom I misunderstood your question. Will edit it again.

Comment: @ltux I already got a solution. Thanks very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet worked for me (using Regex in python3):

```
nonAcceptibleUTF8Chars = list(chr(i) for i in range(161, 255 + 1))
result = re.sub('[' + re.escape(''.join(nonAcceptibleUTF8Chars)) + ']', '', inputString)
```

inputString = VICTORIAÏ¿½S SECRET

result = VICTORIAS SECRET

Though late to the party, Hope this helps! :)